# .sql file to execute multiple DB2 queries

Tags: db2

I have a .sql file which has mutiple sql queries. when executing this file in clp using command

> db2 -vtf C:\path\to\somefile.sql

always getting the error

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0007N  The statement was not processed because a character that is not
>   supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL statement.  Invalid
>   character: "\".  Text preceding the invalid character: "f D:".  SQLSTATE=42601
>   db2 => -tvf D:\testquery.sql

In .sql file i have these export queries.

```
export to ACTIONTAKENMASTER.rar of del select * from SERVEIT.ACTIONTAKENMASTER
export to ACTIVITYACTION.rar of del select * from SERVEIT.ACTIVITYACTION
export to ADDRESSMASTER.rar of del select * from SERVEIT.ADDRESSMASTER
export to ADVISE_INDEX.rar of del select * from SERVEIT.ADVISE_INDEX
```

can anyone help!

Comment: The error does not fit your code

Comment: But i am getting the exact same error with given scenario.

Comment: Where in the file is "D:\testquery.sql"?

Comment: yes the file is in D drive and exact command is -vtf D:\testquery.sql

Comment: But you are executing "db2 -vtf C:\path\to\somefile.sql"...?! I give up

Comment: No no that is just for reference. I am executing -vtf D:\testquery.sql

Comment: Is there any reason for downvote?

Answer (score 2):

With the `-t` option, you're telling the DB2 CLP that your statements are terminated with a semicolon (`;`).  This is overriding the default for the CLP where statements are one-line only.

You have 2 options:

1. Add a semi-colon at the end of each statement
2. Drop the `-t` option:  Execute `db2 -vf C:\path\to\somefile.sql`

Option 2 will only work if each statement in your file is on a single line.

Comment: I have followed both the options but still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to run the command from a DB2 Command Window (which will look like a DOS prompt), not the DB2 Command Line Processor (which has the `db2 =>` prompt).